# jquery open anchor link from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shadowbox

Say I have an anchor link like:

```
<a id="page-contact" rel="shadowbox;width=640;height=400" href="/contact.php">link here</a>
```

How would I be able to open it from jquery i.e.

```
jQuery('#page-contact').click();
```

Obviously that calls the .click event but doesn't do the href if that makes sense.

The object of this is to actually open a lightbox not to change the page like window.location

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the href or open the shadowbox?

Comment: trying to open shadowbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beat the geeks again!

I've done this and it works! :-)

```
Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '/content.php',
        type:     'iframe',
        title:      'Tags',
        height:350,
        width:450
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

To change your current page to the `href` attribute of that element:

```
document.location.href = $('#page-contact').attr('href');
```

**EDIT** now that we have the *real* question, I think you can do this:

```
var obj = Shadowbox.setup('#page-contact');
Shadowbox.open(obj);
```

Comment: Close but that actually changes the page, it's not actually what I want to do. if you notice the rel="shadowbox" this should open a light box...

Comment: ok, was worth a try.  The point was that it's Shadowbox has to do the real work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the browser window to that target (specified in the `href` attribute) do this:

```
window.location.href = $('#page-contact').attr('href');
```

Comment: Close but that actually changes the page, it's not actually what I want to do. if you notice the rel="shadowbox" this should open a light box...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to trigger a click event on a jquery selection use:

```
('#page-contact').trigger('click')
```

Comment: Close but that actually changes the page, it's not actually what I want to do. if you notice the rel="shadowbox" this should open a light box... So call the click - not change the page :)

Comment: If you want to trigger a click event on a jquery selection use:    ('#page-contact').trigger('click');

Comment: Again that only works if I have  onclick="javascript:alert('2');" within the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Use either one of these to trigger a `click` event:

```
$('#page-contact').click();
```

Or…

```
$('#page-contact').trigger('click');
```

If you’ve initialized the Shadowbox plugin correctly, the triggered click will cause the lightbox to appear.

Comment: Again that only works if I have  onclick="javascript:alert('2');" within the anchor tag